# Is there any way to send Image as parameter from c# to python script?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have a standart c# WinForm application. In my application, i must send Image as input to python script and execute my python file which contains some object detection models.

I tried to convert image 1d array and convert it string, send it to python script as parameter but i get error like "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Filename and extension are too long'".

Also I don't want to give image path as a parameter than read image in python file. Because I dont have enough time to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Because I dont have enough time to do it."?

Comment: You can create a simple Flask api and send the image encoded in base64 to an api endpoint from c# code using some sort of httpclient.

Comment: i mean that i have maximum 200 miliseconds to execute python file. So I avoid reading image in python file. I want to directly process the image, which sent as parameter, in python file for saving time. @DiptangsuGoswami

Comment: Try with a Flask api.